# Synchronizing hibernate's session after inserts

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have code that select all rows of a database and deletes them. It performs this process continuously. When there is no data in the database, it sleeps for 2 seconds then tries again. My problem is the following, when new data is added to the database, my code does not see it.

The test:

I ran my code, it was waiting for new data and a few seconds later I manually added data to the database. My code did not see the new row at all. I am 100% sure the data I added is actually in the database.

I am using Hibernate with MySQL.

The code:

```
String queryString = "select * from rawleads";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(queryString);
ArrayList list = (ArrayList) query.list();

while (list.isEmpty()) {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    query = session.createSQLQuery(queryString );
    list = (ArrayList) query.list();
    System.out.println("refreshing table");
}

System.out.println("Processing...");
```

I think it could be related to the cache since the code is unable to see changes made to the database.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You inserted data manually in the database, but did you commit after inserting? Moreover, why do you name your variable hql, since its a SQL query, and not a HQL query? And also, why are you casting the result of query.list() to an ArrayList? Nothing guarantees that you'll get an ArrayList.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, you are right on the variable name. About the ArrayList, we were still working on this and for now we manually convert the DB row into our object. The arrayList was easy to use in order to extract the attributes.

Comment: What does ArrayList provide that List doesn't? You didn't answer the main question: did you commit after inserting?

Comment: Yes I did and I double checked by using another code to fetch the newly inserted row.

Comment: ArrayList? Manually convert the db row? Extract? I think you are doing it wrong! The returned type of the 'list' does not depend on what the query returns; that's what's *inside* the list. Anyway, the whole point of hibernate is avoiding "manual extraction". It is "trivial" to map a class to a table, and you can "trivially" generate the source code for a class that is mapped to a database table. (Trivial if you have done it before, that is...)

Answer (score 2):

You will probably have to create a new transaction before each new iteration.

edit:

```
    while (running) {

        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
        try {
            String queryString = "select * from rawleads";
            SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(queryString);
            List pendingLeads = query.list();

            if (pendingLeads.isEmpty()) {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } else {
                process(pendingLeads);
            }
            t.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            t.rollback();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would he have to do that? could you elaborate? Do you think he's using repeatable_read or serializable isolation level?

Comment: If there IS a transaction started, he won't see any new rows if he is using a sensible isolation level.  I think mysql defaults to repeatable-read. Besides, it's wise to use transactional updates - At least one transaction for each "batch" of read/process/delete.

Comment: OK, I agree with that. I thought the default was read_committed.